# Ambiguous Heritage access data

Tags: c++

I have a problem and I want to resolve it using Inheritance and Polymorphism with C++:

An Equipment may be a device or a cable

Every Equipment has an identifier N

the device has a position : OPEN or CLOSED

the cable has a length L

Every Equipment has a resistance:

```
NULL for a device

coefficient 0.5 of the length for a cable
```

I had made this implementation with C++ classes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class Phy{
    protected :
        float resistance;
    public:
        virtual void updateResistance() = 0;
`       float getResis(){return resistance;}
};
class Device: public Phy{
    protected :
        int position;
    public:
        Device(int pos):position(pos){};
        virtual void updateResistance(){resistance = 0;};
        int GetPos()const{return position;}
};
class Cable: public Phy{
    protected :
        float longeur;
    public:
        Cable(float longeu):longeur(longeu){};
        virtual void updateResistance(){resistance = 0.5 * longeur;};
        float Getlong()const{return longeur;}
};

class Equipement: public Device, public Cable{
    protected :
        int id;
    public:
        Equipement(int idd, float longe = 0,  int pos =0):id(idd),Cable(longe), Device(pos){};
        int GetId()const {return id;}
        float GetResistance(){ return resistance;}
};

int main(){
    Equipement Equip(25, 20, 0);
    Equip.GetResistance();
    
    return 0;
}
```

My question : how can I made an equipement as Cable Only or as a device only?
I have doubts about my architecture, my Equipement Class is both Cable and Device

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should not derive `Equipment` from `Device` or `Cable`. Instead, derive them from `Equipment`.

`Equipment` should implement things that are common to both, and `Device` and `Cable` should implement things that are specific to each class.

Resistance should be implemented as `virtual` function in `Equipment` class, which is overriden in each derived class.

```
class Equipment {
    // N
    // virtual resistance
};

class Device : public Equipment {
    // position
    // resistance: NULL
};

class Cable : public Equipment {
    // L
    // resistance: 0.5 * L
};
```

To use polymorphism, you should create the objects as pointers, for example:

```
Equipment* eq = new Cable;
```

Comment: Thank you VLL for your anwser, I correct my architecture :

Answer (score 0):

Now this is my corrected implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class Equipment {
    protected :
       int id;
       float resistance;
    public:
        Equipment(int idd):id(idd){ };
        int GetId()const {return id;}
        virtual float GetResistance()= 0;
};

class Device : public Equipment {
    protected :
       int position;
    public:
       Device(int id, int pos):position(pos),Equipment(id){};
       virtual float GetResistance(){resistance = 0;
                                     return resistance;};
       int GetPos()const{return position;}
 };

class Cable : public Equipment {
    protected :
       float length;
    public:
       Cable(int id, float lon):length(lon),Equipment(id){};
       virtual float GetResistance(){resistance = 0.5 * length;return resistance;};
       float Getlong()const{return length;}
};

int main()
{
    list<Equipment*> lstEqui;
    lstEqui.push_back(new Cable(334, 20));
    lstEqui.push_back(new Device(678, 5));
    list<Equipment*>::iterator it;
    for(it = lstEqui.begin(); it != lstEqui.end();it++)
    {
      cout <<"id="<< (*it)->GetId()<< "  "<<"Position ="<<(*it)->GetPos() << " resistance= "<<(*it)->GetResistance()<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My question is how can I display Position for Device instance and Lenght for Cable instance?

I got an error that GetPos() is not a member of Equipment Class

Comment: if you are sure that your pointer-to-object is of class Device, you can use `Device* device_ptr = static_cast<Device*>(equipment_ptr)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).